# Reset a component property after event binding in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm curious to see if Angular offers a way to reset my component property with just a single event binding rather than having to specify two bindings to get the job done.

I know I can do this:

```
<div 
 (mouseover)="componentProperty = 'hasValue'"
 (mouseout)= "componentProperty = undefined"
></div>
```

But is there a way I can have the component property reset when only (mouseover) is not happening?

Comment: If event doesn't happen it means it never did, so OnInit or other life cycle hook could set `undefined` to your properties. Can't fully understand what's your issue..

Comment: No, there is no such thing.